# Add custom text next to each variation in dropdown

Tags: woocommerce

I have one product that has 4 variations.
The product is a ring and the variations are sizes.
Each product is imported via WP All Import and each variation is created with an imported attribute that is set to 'use as variation'.

The attribuses are a list of sizes like 50, 52, ...
In some countries those sizes are different and set like 15.9, 16.2, ...
I would like to add those different sizes next to my existing attributes like 50 (15.9).
Is there a way I can link these custom labels to my existing attributes?

I found ways to add sold out and pricing next to it but not custom labels that are different for each attribute.

Maybe there is a way to add them as custom fields and get and link them from the database?

Thank you for all input and possible solutions.

Kind regards
Ely

Comment: You should look at this [**question / answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47183866/3730754) as it could be a good track  for your case…

Comment: Thanks. This helped!