# How to add "out of stock" in the dropdown selector?

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, user-registration

Tell me how to add the inscription "Out of Stock" when choosing the size of the product?

In the drop-down list need to show all sizes of clothes. If the size is not available, then we write "Out of Stock". If the size is available, then choose size of clothes.

[Here is an example](https://www.net-a-porter.com/ru/en/product/1074777/paul___joe/wrap-effect-floral-print-silk-chiffon-top)

I put the code that LoicTheAztec offers

[How to add variation stock status to Woocommerce product variation dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180058/how-to-add-variation-stock-status-to-woocommerce-product-variation-dropdown)

When editing the product I put all the sizes, two "in stock", the rest are "out of stock".

At me at all sizes of clothes there was an inscription "Out of Stock", though the attribute "size" only one in the dropdown list.

How can this be remedied?

> **EDIT:**
>
> The Answer made by LoicTheAztec has been updated **and works** as intended.

Comment: Code updated - There was a variable bad name in the first function in this updated line: `if($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug )`and It will work only for variable products that have 1 attribute for variations (so 1 dropdown)… Tested and works on Woocommerce last version...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Everything is working.
When I select the size, the product status is duplicated before the "Add Cart" button. How can I remove it?

Comment: The product status is not duplicated, but simply displayed (by default) with the number of items in stock when stock management is enabled at product level. So it's not the same thing. If you want to hide it you can use CSS or ask a new question.