# Show the custom attribute "variable product" in the list of related products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

Based on *"[How to add variation stock status to Woocommerce product variation dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180058/how-to-add-variation-stock-status-to-woocommerce-product-variation-dropdown/47189725#47189725)"* answer, 
 I have made some code that shows the custom attribute of a variable product and its presence in the store:

```
// Function that will check the stock status and display the corresponding additional text
function get_stock_status_text($product, $name, $term_slug) {
    foreach($product - > get_available_variations() as $variation) {
            if ($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug)
                    $stock = $variation['is_in_stock'];
    }

    return $stock == 1 ? '' : ' - out of stock';
}

// The hooked function that will add the stock status to the dropdown options elements.
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'show_stock_status_in_dropdown', 10, 2);

function show_stock_status_in_dropdown($html, $args) {
    // Only if there is a unique variation attribute (one dropdown)
    if (sizeof($args['product'] - > get_variation_attributes()) == 1):

            $options = $args['options'];
    $product = $args['product'];
    $attribute = $args['attribute']; // The product attribute taxonomy
    $name = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_'.sanitize_title($attribute);
    $id = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title($attribute);
    $class = $args['class'];
    $show_option_none = $args['show_option_none'] ? true : false;
    $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __('Select size', 'woocommerce');

    if (empty($options) && !empty($product) && !empty($attribute)) {
            $attributes = $product - > get_variation_attributes();
            $options = $attributes[$attribute];
    }

    $html = '<select id="'.esc_attr($id).
    '" class="'.esc_attr($class).
    '" name="'.esc_attr($name).
    '" data-attribute_name="attribute_'.esc_attr(sanitize_title($attribute)).
    '" data-show_option_none="'.($show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no').
    '">';
    $html. = '<option value="">'.esc_html($show_option_none_text).
    '</option>';

    if (!empty($options)) {
            if ($product && taxonomy_exists($attribute)) {
                    $terms = wc_get_product_terms($product - > get_id(), $attribute, array('fields' => 'all'));

                    foreach($terms as $term) {
                            if (in_array($term - > slug, $options)) {
                                    // HERE Added the function to get the text status
                                    $stock_status = get_stock_status_text($product, $name, $term - > slug);
                                    $html. = '<option value="'.esc_attr($term - > slug).
                                    '" '.selected(sanitize_title($args['selected']), $term - > slug, false).
                                    '>'.esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term - > name).$stock_status).
                                    '</option>';
                            }
                    }
            } else {
                    foreach($options as $option) {
                            $selected = sanitize_title($args['selected']) === $args['selected'] ? selected($args['selected'], sanitize_title($option), false) : selected($args['selected'], $option, false);
                            // HERE Added the function to get the text status
                            $stock_status = get_the_stock_status($product, $name, $option);
                            $html. = '<option value="'.esc_attr($option).
                            '" '.$selected.
                            '>'.esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option).$stock_status).
                            '</option>';
                    }
            }
    }
    $html. = '</select>';

    endif;

    return $html;
}
```

On a single product page, I show related products. How to show this attribute (its presence in the store) in the form of a label in related products?

For example:

The product's name

Price - $25

Sizes available: L, XL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, I hooked into the `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` and displayed the product attributes. Right now it only works for the size attribute. It is showing the Large, Medium, Small. If you want to show L, XL, M, etc. just edit the size attribute.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'mamham_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 10);
function mamham_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item() {
    global $product;

    // Bail if not in the single product page.
    if ( ! is_product() ) return;

    // Prduct attributes which you want to show.
    // Attributes to show in the slug.
    // 'attribute slug' => 'Text shown';
    $show_attributes = array(
        'size' => 'Sizes available:',
    );

    // Get the slugs.
    $show_slugs = array_keys( $show_attributes );

    // Get product type.
    $product_type = $product->get_type();

    if( 'simple' === $product_type ) {  
        $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        foreach( $product_attributes as $key => $product_attribute ) {
            $slug = substr( $key, 3 );
            if ( in_array( $slug, $show_slugs, TRUE ) ) {
                $terms = $product_attribute->get_terms();
                $terms_output = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'name');
                $terms_output = implode(', ', $terms_output );
                echo esc_html( "${show_attributes[$slug]} ${terms_output}" );
            }
        }

    } elseif ( 'variable' === $product_type ) {
        $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();     
        foreach ( $product_variations as $product_variation ) {
            if ( $product_variation['is_in_stock'] && isset( $product_variation['attributes']['attribute_pa_size'] )) {
                $terms_output[] = ucwords( $product_variation['attributes']['attribute_pa_size'] );
            }           
        }       
        if ( ! empty( $terms_output) ) {
            $terms_output = implode(', ', $terms_output );
            echo esc_html( "Sizes available: ${terms_output}" );
        }       
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot, I have storefront theme and WooCommerce installed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my attributes of variable products are not shows. Do you show all product attributes or only those that are in stock? Can you show a screenshot of how the attributes of the product are configured?

Comment: if you want to show the attributes of variable products and those in stock, then I have to update the code. Do you want to show one attribute or all?

Comment: I want to show only those attributes that are available. For example, I have variable products with sizes: S, M, L, XL, XXL. Only L and XL are available. These are the sizes I want to show.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Everything is working. I will test this functionality for some time.

Comment: @Dmitry Let me know, if anything happens.

Comment: Sorry, how to show the attributes that are in stock, only in Upsells products? Currently, attributes are shown on ALL products.

Comment: @Dmitry Let me look on that.

Comment: @Dmitry I understood your problem. You want to show the available sizes only in the related or upsell products, right?

Comment: @Dmitry I apologize for the late reply. I got caught in my office work. I have updated the code. Let me know, anything.