# WooCommerce: Add class to variation dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add the class `.form-control` to the variation dropdown in the WooCommerce product pages.

It seems that there is an option to do so. I found the function `wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options`.

The function has an class attribute:

```
function wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( $args = array() ) { 
$args = wp_parse_args( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', $args ), array( 
    'options' => false,  
    'attribute' => false,  
    'product' => false,  
    'selected' => false,  
    'name' => '',  
    'id' => '',  
    'class' => '',  
    'show_option_none' => __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' ),  
 ) );
```

Is there any solution to add the class to the dropdown?
I only found the function but no code/snippet to change the class attribute.

Edit: I found a snippet that is customizing the dropdown but I don't know how to use it for only adding the class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47189725/1788961

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', $args )`

You basically need to use that filter to access the `$args` that are being passed. In your particular situation, this is how you would do it:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', static function( $args ) {
    $args['class'] = 'form-control';
    return $args;
}, 2 );
```

What this does, is hooks into the `woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args` filter and passes the original `$args` to a static function. Then you basically set the value of the `class` index of the `$args` array. Then you return the `$args`.

Comment: This is 100% accurate! In the filter description, there is all the possible args which can be alterate to do more than just adding a class.