# Woocommerce - How to conditionally change button text on variable product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I spent my day trying to understand how can I set a conditional button for my **variable products** based on stock. I followed and searched all tips, discussions, etc... But nothing is OK.

The idea is :

1. if **no variation selected** : **Pick your style**
2. if variation is **available** : **add to cart**
3. if the variation is **not available** or out of stock : disable the button "add to cart" and change text to "sold out"
4. if all variations are **out of stock** : disable "add to cart" and change text to "sold out"

I've tried different snippets, I'm quite a beginner... I also tried dynamically changing text inside the button with jQuery, because I have the following class : `wc-variation-is-unavailable` when a variation is out of stock.. The thing I succeeded was to make the button grey :D But It still clickable..

This is the last snippet I tried, but it changes the button label for all variations :/

```
    function ace_custom_change_singe_add_to_cart_text( $text, $product ) {
    global $product;
    $text = __( 'Add to basket' );
    $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' )) {
        if ($stock > 1) {
            $text = __( 'Pick your style' );
        }
        elseif ($stock == 0) {
            $text = __( 'Sold Out' );
        }
    }   

    if ( $product->is_type( 'grouped' )) {
        $text = __( 'View components' );
    }


    // Set a button text for a specific category
    $category = get_term_by( 'slug', 'wine', 'product_cat' );
    if ( $category && in_array( $category->term_id, $product->get_category_ids() ) ) {
        $text = __( 'Pick this bottle' );
    }

    return $text; 
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'ace_custom_change_singe_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
```

This is in my variable.php file :

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

        <div class="single_variation_wrap">
            <?php

                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );
                do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' );
                ?>

                <div class="variations_button">

                    <?php if (StockieSettings::get('woocommerce_add_to_cart_ajax', 'global')) { ?>
                    <a id="dyId" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn alt btn-loading-disabled">
                        <i class="icon ion ion-left">
                            <svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 12 16" xml:space="preserve">
                            <path class="st0" d="M9,4V3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3S3,1.3,3,3v1H0v10c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h8c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V4H9z M4,3c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2
                                s2,0.9,2,2v1H4V3z"/>
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                        <?php echo (esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text()) ); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn alt btn-loading-disabled">

                        <i class="icon ion ion-left">
                            <svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 12 16" xml:space="preserve">
                            <path class="st0" d="M9,4V3c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3S3,1.3,3,3v1H0v10c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h8c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V4H9z M4,3c0-1.1,0.9-2,2-2
                                s2,0.9,2,2v1H4V3z"/>
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                        <?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?>
                    </button>
                <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="" />

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' ); ?>
                </div>
```

If someone can help, I will be really grateful.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47183866/6670570

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer :-) I tried this yesterday before posting here, but it’s not working for me. The thing I want to change is the add to cart button for variations individually and globally if some variations are out of stock :/

Comment: To do that you will need to access the variations of the product as shown in the answer. Your code is only accessing the product.