# WooCommerce - add custom class to variation option from dropdown select list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I try do add custom class to the variations select list. I know how to add class to the SELECT tag, but I can't traget each option from this list. I need to add custom class to the option tags.

here is my function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'my_dropdown_choice' );
/**
 * Add class to option from variation list
 */
function my_dropdown_choice( $add_class ){
        if( is_product() ) {
                $add_class['class'] = 'my_custom_class';
        }  
        return $add_class;    
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce has no hook that allows you to value the class attribute for each option of the product variations form but as you say it values the class attribute only for the `select` element.

To do this you will need to create a custom variation form using the **`woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html`** hook.

**WooCommerce Code Reference**: [woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.3056)

You can find an example here:

- [How to add variation stock status to Woocommerce product variation dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180058/how-to-add-variation-stock-status-to-woocommerce-product-variation-dropdown)