# Add Stock Status boolean as custom attribute of WooCommerce variation selector

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47189725/1092677), provided by LoicTheAztec. It adds stock status related text to the variation selector on WooCommerce products. It works as required.

I would, however, like to also add a custom attribute to each `<option ... >` in the dropdown selector.

My reason for this is that I am writing some jQuery that will be triggered by whether or not the selected `option` is in stock. That will be cleanest if each `option` has a stock attribute. For example, `<option value=“1kg” class=“ ... “ stock-status=“true”>1kg - (in stock)</option>`. In this example I’ve added a custom attribute called `stock-status`, which will either be `true` or `false`.

The code in use is:

```
// Function that will check the stock status and display the corresponding additional text
function get_stock_status_text( $product, $name, $term_slug ){
    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        if($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug ) {
            $stock = $variation['is_in_stock'];
            break;
        }
    }
    return $stock == 1 ? ' - (In Stock)' : ' - (Out of Stock)';
}

// The hooked function that will add the stock status to the dropdown options elements.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'show_stock_status_in_dropdown', 10, 2);
function show_stock_status_in_dropdown( $html, $args ) {
    // Only if there is a unique variation attribute (one dropdown)
    if( sizeof($args['product']->get_variation_attributes()) == 1 ) :

    $options               = $args['options'];
    $product               = $args['product'];
    $attribute             = $args['attribute']; // The product attribute taxonomy
    $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $class                 = $args['class'];
    $show_option_none      = $args['show_option_none'] ? true : false;
    $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' );

    if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
    }

    $html = '<select id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" data-show_option_none="' . ( $show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no' ) . '">';
    $html .= '<option value="">' . esc_html( $show_option_none_text ) . '</option>';

    if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
        if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
            $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                    // HERE Added the function to get the text status
                    $stock_status = get_stock_status_text( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                    $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . $stock_status ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                $selected = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? selected( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : selected( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                // HERE Added the function to get the text status
                $stock_status = get_stock_status_text( $product, $name, $option );
                $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) . $stock_status ) . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html .= '</select>';

    endif;

    return $html;
}
```

My knowledge of PHP isn’t sufficient to know the best way to go about this. One crude method would be to test if the result of `get_stock_status_text` contains the string `(In` or `(No`, and then add `stock-status=“true”` (or false) too the `$html` output accordingly. I can likely come up with a way to do that, but I suspect that’s not the best way to go about it. I am thinking it would be better to set a variable as `true` or `false` within the `get_stock_status_text` function, and then based on the value of that a `stock-status` custom attribute would have a value of `true|false` accordingly.

What would be an efficient way to add a custom attribute to the `$html` output, with a `true|false` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of playing around, it looks like I’ve come up with a solution. If there’s a more efficient or tidier way to achieve the result, I’d be very interested to know. This solution does at least have the desired output.

I have modified the code (from my question) to the following:

```
/******* ADD STOCK STATUS TO DROP DOWN SELECTOR ******/
// Function that will check the stock status and display the corresponding additional text
function get_stock_status_text( $product, $name, $term_slug ){
    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        if($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug ) {
            $stock = $variation['is_in_stock'];
            break;
        }
    }
    return $stock == 1 ? '&nbsp;- (In Stock)' : '&nbsp;- (No Stock)';
}

function get_stock_status_bool( $product, $name, $term_slug ){
    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        if($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug ) {
            $stock_bool = $variation['is_in_stock'];
            break;
        }
    }
    return $stock_bool == 1 ? 'true' : 'false';
}

// The hooked function that will add the stock status to the dropdown options elements.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'show_stock_status_in_dropdown', 10, 2);
function show_stock_status_in_dropdown( $html, $args ) {
    // Only if there is a unique variation attribute (one dropdown)
    if( sizeof($args['product']->get_variation_attributes()) == 1 ) :

    $options               = $args['options'];
    $product               = $args['product'];
    $attribute             = $args['attribute']; // The product attribute taxonomy
    $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $class                 = $args['class'];
    $show_option_none      = $args['show_option_none'] ? true : false;
    $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' );

    if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
    }

    $html = '<select id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" data-show_option_none="' . ( $show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no' ) . '">';
    $html .= '<option value="">' . esc_html( $show_option_none_text ) . '</option>';

    if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
        if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
            $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                    // HERE Added the function to get the text status
                    $stock_status = get_stock_status_text( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                    $stock_attr = get_stock_status_bool( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                    $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . ' stock-status="' . $stock_attr . '">' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . $stock_status ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                $selected = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? selected( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : selected( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                // HERE Added the function to get the text status
                $stock_status = get_stock_status_text( $product, $name, $option );
                $stock_attr = get_stock_status_bool( $product, $name, $term->slug );

                $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $selected . ' stock-status="' . $stock_attr . '">' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) . $stock_status ) . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html .= '</select>';

    endif;

    return $html;
}
```

The main addition is a new function, `get_stock_status_bool`. Which is a replica of `get_stock_status_text` except that it returns `true` or `false`.

This function is then called right after the `get_stock_status_text` function is called, and its value is assigned to `$stock_attr`.
`$stock_attr` has then been added into the `$html` value (e.g. `<option value=“1 kg” selected=“selected” stock-status=“true” class=“ ...”>1kg - $150 - (In Stock)</option>`