# Elementor add to cart widget not graying out unavailable variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, elementor

I'm using a php snippet that grays out unavailable variations here:

```php
if (!function_exists('ace_grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock')) 
{
  function ace_grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock($is_active, $variation) 
  {
    if (!$variation->is_in_stock()) 
    {
      $is_active = false;
    }
    return $is_active;
  }

  add_filter('woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'ace_grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock', 10, 2);
}
```

This code is not graying them out in the elementor add to cart widget.

You can see it in action here if you select variation 201. It should be grayed out but it isn't.

https://creekwalkcottages.com/reserve/lot/

Comment: You need to search and ask in Elementor plugin support pages…

Answer (score 0):

This snippet:

```html
// Function that will check the stock status and display the corresponding additional text
function get_stock_status_text( $product, $name, $term_slug ){
    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        if($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug ) {
            $stock = $variation['is_in_stock'];
            break;
        }
    }
    return $stock == 1 ? ' - (In Stock)' : ' - (Out of Stock)';
}

// The hooked function that will add the stock status to the dropdown options elements.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'show_stock_status_in_dropdown', 10, 2);
function show_stock_status_in_dropdown( $html, $args ) {
    // Only if there is a unique variation attribute (one dropdown)
    if( sizeof($args['product']->get_variation_attributes()) == 1 ) :

    $options               = $args['options'];
    $product               = $args['product'];
    $attribute             = $args['attribute']; // The product attribute taxonomy
    $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $class                 = $args['class'];
    $show_option_none      = $args['show_option_none'] ? true : false;
    $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' );

    if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
    }

    $html = '<select id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" data-show_option_none="' . ( $show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no' ) . '">';
    $html .= '<option value="">' . esc_html( $show_option_none_text ) . '</option>';

    if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
        if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
            $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                    // HERE Added the function to get the text status
                    $stock_status = get_stock_status_text( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                    $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . $stock_status ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                $selected = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? selected( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : selected( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                // HERE Added the function to get the text status
                $stock_status = get_stock_status_text( $product, $name, $option );
                $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) . $stock_status ) . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html .= '</select>';

    endif;

    return $html;
}
```

allows for it to show "in stock" or "out of stock". It doesn't gray it out.

Source:
[How to add variation stock status to Woocommerce product variation dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180058/how-to-add-variation-stock-status-to-woocommerce-product-variation-dropdown?rq=2)